# Java script : Calling Flask API with AJAX fails

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I am trying a simple Flask API in JS and it fails. I tested the URL using curl and it works fine. Not sure where I am doing it wrong. Your help is much appreciated.

the http response code is fine (200). May be something wrong in the way i wrote the js....

python script:

```
from flask import Flask
import simplejson as json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/person', methods=['GET'])
def get_person():
    str = {'id':'1','first_name':'John','last_name':'Smith'}
    res = json.dumps(str)
    return res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

testapp.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:5000/api/person",
        success: function(data){
           $('.person-id').append(data.id);
           $('.person-first_name').append(data.first_name);
           $('.person-status').append('success');
        },
        error: function(){
           $('.person-status').append('failed');
        }

    });
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TestApp jQuery</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="testapp.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <p class="person-status">The Status is </p>
            <p class="person-id">The ID is </p>
            <p class="person-first_name">First name is </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[html response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM7Y4.jpg)

[curl testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqOXt.jpg)

Comment: What does your browser's console say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your api returns a stringify json,

try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/api/person",
    success: function(data){
       data=JSON.parse(data)
       $('.person-id').append(data.id);
       $('.person-first_name').append(data.first_name);
       $('.person-status').append('success');
    },
    error: function(){
       $('.person-status').append('failed');
    }
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType:"json",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/api/person",
    success: function(data){
       $('.person-id').append(data.id);
       $('.person-first_name').append(data.first_name);
       $('.person-status').append('success');
    },
    error: function(){
       $('.person-status').append('failed');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: could you give us the error from that error callback?

Comment: forget to put, where do you run your web, e.g. which port? probably because of cross-origin problem

Comment: it looks like cross-origin is the issue. I run it localhost with port 5000. I changed it to XMLHttpRequest and it works fine.